# what is the purpose of std::set<VALUE, std::owner_less<VALUE>>?

Tags: c++, set, std, owner

I'm trying to dissect this websocket++ example https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/experimental/examples/broadcast_server/broadcast_server.cpp

At line 126, there is `typedef std::set<connection_hdl,std::owner_less<connection_hdl>> con_list;`.  I'm wondering why it isn't merely `typedef std::set<connection_hdl> con_list;`.

I've read [How does the Comma Operator work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work) and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/owner_less but I'm not sure what the purpose is.

What is actually stored in the `std::set`?  What does `std::owner_less` actually do?  What is the purpose of making a container with this structure instead of storing the `connection_hdl`s themselves?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the comma operator, and the page you linked to for `std::owner_less` should answer your question directly.

Comment: `std::set` takes multiple template parameters, but only the first is explicitly required; the rest have default types if you don't define them. The second parameter is a binary function used for sorting.

Comment: BTW, `connection_hdl` is a `std::weak_ptr<void>`.

Comment: @Joe : If you read the page you linked to, you would know that `std::weak_ptr<>` has no `operator<`, so it simply wouldn't compile without a special comparitor. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn ohhhhhhhhhhh, ok.  I'm new to c++, so it took a while to sink in lol.  you made it much clearer.  ty!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with comma operator. A `set<T>` requires that `T` be less-than-comparable, i.e. `operator <` should be defined for `T`. The reason for this is that the set keeps its elements in an ordered fashion(via one kind of tree or another). You can supply a set with a second template argument - a functor that compares two elements so that the set can use that comparison. [`std::owner_less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/owner_less) is a predicate template that operates on shared and weak pointers and performs owner-based (as opposed to value-based) ordering.